# Extension of Visual studio code to change 3 equal mark into 3 horizontal lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

It does not relate to code, but I want to know which extension of VSC can turn 3 equal mark into 3 horizontal lines OR >= mark into ≥ mark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No extension needed, just edit your `settings.json`

```
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
```

> Enables/Disables font ligatures ('calt' and 'liga' font features). Change this to a string for fine-grained control of the 'font-feature-settings' CSS property.

You do need to have a font selected that does support those ligatures.

Comment: so I only need insert `"editor.fontLigatures": true,` to settings.json?

Comment: Yes, that and having a font selected that does support those combined characters (not all fonts will).

Comment: I tried it and succeed. Thanks for supporting :)